# 'str' object has no attribute 'visible_fields'; django class based views

Tags: django, forms, django-class-based-views

I've been struggling with class views all day after starting on them yesterday. My issue is constantly getting `'str' object has no attribute 'visible_fields'`, so the 'form' item below is not really a form:

template-

```
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form|bootstrap}}
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add new article"/>
</form>
```

view-

```
class ArticleCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Article
    template_name = 'index/add_article.html'
    form_class = ArticleForm

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        article_form = self.get_form()
        if article_form.is_valid():
            article = article_form.save(commit=False)
            title   = article_form.cleaned_data['title']
            url     = article_form.cleaned_data['url']
            title = process_title(url)
            article.title = title
            article.save()
            return redirect("index:article_list")
        else:
            form = ArticleForm()
            print type(form)
            print dir(self)
            return render(request, 'index/add_article.html')
```

The worst part is printing `type(form)` shows it is `<class 'index.forms.ArticleForm'>`. I'm trying to just have it redirect to the list view if the form saved, and replay the form with the error (You already have an article with that URL) if the form is bad. I heard class views are easier to work with and huge projects I've read through use them, but they really seem worse than the old views. I assume that's because I'm not using them well

Every example I've seen has a template getting a "form" somehow, like

```
class RangeCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Range
    template_name = 'dashboard/ranges/range_form.html'
    form_class = RangeForm

    def get_success_url(self):
        if 'action' in self.request.POST:
            return reverse('dashboard:range-products',
                           kwargs={'pk': self.object.id})
        else:
            msg = render_to_string(
                'dashboard/ranges/messages/range_saved.html',
                {'range': self.object})
            messages.success(self.request, msg, extra_tags='safe noicon')
            return reverse('dashboard:range-list')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ctx = super(RangeCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        ctx['title'] = _("Create range")
        return ctx
```

then like magic in `range_form.html`:

{% include "dashboard/partials/form_fields.html" with form=form %}

My issue here is I need to process the title of the form, with

```
def process_title(url):
    def _search_for_title(url):
        try:
            r = requests.get(url)
            content = r.text
            t = html.document_fromstring(content)
            return t.find(".//title").text
        except IOError:
            return None

    title = _search_for_title(url)
    return title or 'None'
```

This kind of ruins the purpose of a class based view. It seems I should be processing the title by overriding 'clean' in the form itself?

Otherwise, how can I make this view pass a form object, render it in the template, and just re-render the template if the form didn't pass?

And how can I access the form in the template?

Thank you

Comment: How? By doing the same as the example view, rather than overriding `post` instead as you are doing.

Comment: so I should process changing the title in the form's clean method before it reaches the view?

Comment: that's what I'm trying now

Comment: But what are you asking for? In title of question you're asking why form is type of 'str' in template, but in explanation you're asking how to process title of form properly.

Comment: I realized halfway through I should just process the fields within the form, and that fixed my issue, but my question is still why did "form" not show up available in the template like normal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do it by following the example view, rather than overriding `post` instead as you are doing.

In your case, simply displaying and processing a form is the *default behaviour* of a CreateView. So there is no need to override any methods at all. Your view should just be:

```
class ArticleCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Article
    template_name = 'index/add_article.html'
    form_class = ArticleForm
```

Comment: actually mr. Roseman I need to process the title (when they submit form). `title = process_title(url)` will try to grab the html title element if the user doesn't enter a title, and my form placeholder tells them "I'll try to grab the title" if they leave "Title" blank. How do I do some basic processing of 'title' without fouling up my view like I did above?

Comment: You can override `form_valid` and `form_invalid` methods, or override post but by calling parent method using super.