# 'str' object has no attribute 'visible_fields'

Tags: python, django

I keep getting this error:

```
'str' object has no attribute 'visible_fields'
{% load bootstrap %}
{{ wizard.management_form }}
<div class="form-horizontal">
      {{ wizard.form|bootstrap_horizontal:'col-sm-3 col-md-3' }}
</div>
```

but i really have no idea where does it come from, can anyone help me?

This is what my login view looks like:

```
def login_request(request):

    if request.method == "POST":

        if result['success']:
            form = AuthenticationForm(request, data=request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
                password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
                user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)


                if user is not None:
                    login(request, user)
                    messages.info(request, f"You are now logged in as {username}")
                    return redirect("main:homepage")
                else:
                    messages.error(request, "Invalid username or password")

            else:
                messages.error(request, "Invalid username or password")

    form = AuthenticationForm()
    return render(request,
                  "log.html",
                  {"form":form})
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['str' object has no attribute 'visible\_fields'; django class based views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31908403/str-object-has-no-attribute-visible-fields-django-class-based-views)

Comment: How could it be a duplicate?

Comment: @Jack022, you might have figured this out by now, but it just means someone asked a similar question and best practices around here is to just refer similar questions to questions that already have an answer.